# making 2 get calls from UI or combining 2 calls in the backend

Tags: rest

lets say i have a UI web app with multiple screens and one of the screens makes 2 calls 2 different end points(with in same service-A), but 2 different endpoint pupose is different.

so what is the best practice , since it is going to the same service, instead of making 2 calls from UI. is it better to combine both of them in 1 endpoint and handle those 2 calls in the backend ?